# Stripe API: getting a dispute object from payment intent ID

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

How would one find a dispute object for a specific payment using the stripe API?

This is how you retrieve a dispute object:

```js
const dispute = await stripe.disputes.retrieve(
  'dp_1MEF04LLBOhef2QNK9vzmtDT'
);
```

But how would you get this dispute object given the payment intent id? I haven't been able to find the dispute id from the stripe site either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the correlating dispute objects to a specific Payment Intent you can make ['List All Disputes' API request](https://stripe.com/docs/api/disputes/list#list_disputes-payment_intent) by passing the `payment_intent` parameter. Your code should look something like this:

```
const disputes = await stripe.disputes.list({
    payment_intent: 'pi_123abd', 
  });
```

The response will list all of the dispute objects related to the specific Payment Intent id.